# How to use <select> v-model with vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a `<select>` in my template:

```
<select v-model="amount" required>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    amount: '',
  }
}
```

Can I somehow put `amount` in vuex state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  First, setup your Vuex store to hold the value and the mutation:

***store***

```js
state: {
  amount: null
},
mutations: {
  SET_AMOUNT(state, payload) {
    state.amount = payload;
  }
}
```

You need a way to call the mutation when the model changes and to update the model if the state changes.  A [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) is an elegant tool to handle both directions and avoid improperly mutating Vuex state in the component:

Create a `computed` in the component:

***component***

```js
computed: {
  amount: {
    get() { return this.$store.state.amount },
    set(value) { this.$store.commit('SET_AMOUNT', value) }
  }
}
```

This will work with the template the way it is in your post.